Can I use "is" in typescript for property?
I want to narrow the type of a property using "is".
class Person{
    name:string|undefined;

    //I want the return type to be as follows: 
    hasName()// :this.name is string
    {
        return this.name!=undefined && this.name !=="";
    }
}

const me=new Person();

if (me.hasName()) {
    //This has an error.
    //'me.name' is possibly 'undefined'.
    console.log(me.name.includes("a"));
}


But I don't know if this is possible.
I checked the documentation and the only examples I found were of narrowing the argument types.

Seems a bit like an XY problem. Are you perhaps trying to crowbar a different solution to the problem you have? Seems to me you want to know whether the person is "initialised" (has a name) or not (it's undefined). Therefore, I'd probably approach it with type Person = InitialisedPerson | UninitialisedPerson where interface InitialisedPerson { name: string } and UninitialisedPerson { name: undefined }. Then narrow that. It more strongly defines what you have rather than harder to follow logic.

Relevant for the name != "": Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names + Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names – With Examples

You can use it like this, but there's no specific type for an empty or not empty string, so you could use some branded type:
Playground
declare const nonEmptyString: unique symbol
type NonEmptyString = string & { [nonEmptyString]: true }

class Person{
    name:string|undefined;

    hasName(): this is {name: NonEmptyString}
    {
        return this.name!=undefined && this.name !=="";
    }
}

const me=new Person();

if (me.hasName()) {
    console.log(me.name.includes("a"));
}

